# How to create transparent command bar WHEN IT IS CLOSED in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8

I see that the Opacity attribute of the CommandBar makes trasparent its content when it is opened: however when it is closed it is not transparent (as it was the ApplicationBar in Windows Phone 8).

I would like to have a transparency like the one it is also now possible to set in the StatusBar.

Any suggestion?

Regards
Enso Contini

Answer (score 1):

Random guess - perhaps you need to do this (somewhere in the app's initialization):

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);
```

It makes the page go "under" the app bar, and so if it has transparency, you'll be able to see the page through it.